# Customize KDE PlasmaShell task switchers?

Tags: kde5

I am using the ThumbnailGrid task switcher, which I downloaded through the *Configure Desktop > Window Management > Task Switcher* interface. However, for my usual number of open windows, often not all windows fit into the View;

I'd like to avoid scrolling in the task Switcher, and want to customize the thumbnail size for that purpose.

This task-switcher does not provide any way to configure it through the GUI configuration dialogs.

*This answer is written as Q&A based on the solution I found.*

Answer (score 0):

For KDE5/PlasmaShell I proceeded as such:

1. Locate the files of the downloaded task switcher. In my case this was

   ```
   $HOME/.local/share/kwin/tabbox/thumbnail_grid
   ```

   preinstalled task switchers are in `/usr/share/kwin/tabbox` on my system.
2. Find the associated QML file, in my case

   ```
   $HOME/.local/share/kwin/tabbox/thumbnail_grid/contents/ui/main.qml
   ```
3. Rename the corresponding `*.qmlc` file to `*.qmlc.bak`. I am not sure if this part was needed though.
4. Edit the code as needed. This requires some basic understanding of programming, but not really knowledge of the QML language, depending on what you want to do. In my case I tracked down the thumbnail width configuration to the line

   ```
   property int thumbnailWidth: 300
   ```

   and changed the value to 200.
5. Now KWin needs to be restarted. In KDE5, the following command worked:

   ```
   kwin_x11 --replace & disown
   ```

   where the `disown` part detaches the process from the current shell.